# How to use precacheImage function in flutter?

Tags: caching, flutter, flutter-layout, imagelist, flutter-sliver

Unable to use [precacheImage](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/precacheImage.html) function to load and cache the local images from assets to GridView or ListView in flutter.

***ISSUE: When scrolling the list, images always reload.***

```
class AppLandingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  AppLandingPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: DrawerPage(),
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return getToolbarWidget("Home title");
          },
          body: setDataToContainer(),
        ));
  }
}

Container setDataToContainer() {
  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.0, right: 4, bottom: 4, top: 4),
    child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              HeaderWidget("Header 1"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget("title", "key_x", "pnl.svg"),
              BodyWidget("title2", "key_x", "cls.svg"),
              BodyWidget(
                  "title3", "key_x", "irr.svg"),
              BodyWidget(
                  "title4", "key_x", "icp.svg"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              HeaderWidget("Header 2"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget("title5", "key_x", "ict.svg"),
              BodyWidget("title6", "key_x", "icc.svg"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              HeaderWidget("Others"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            [
              BodyWidget("title7", "key_x", "icd.svg"),
              BodyWidget("title8", "6", "ici.svg"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class HeaderWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  HeaderWidget(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10, bottom: 2, top: 20),
      child: Text(
        text.toUpperCase(),
        style: TextStyle(
            color: hexToColor(themeColor1),
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}

class BodyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  final String title;
  final String navigationKey;

  BodyWidget(this.title, this.navigationKey, this.imagePath);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Card(
          color: hexToColor(themeColor1),
          elevation: 5,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              navigateToView(context, navigationKey);
            },
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/images/$imagePath",
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: 35,
                      height: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.up,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.2),
                        child: Text(
                          title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  void navigateToView(BuildContext context, String navigationKey) {

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) {
          return NewSections();
        },
        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2, child) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation1,
            child: child,
          );
        },
        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: post your code then

Comment: your caode does not use `precacheImage` anywhere

Comment: When I tried this 

 @override
  void initState() {
  // adjust the provider based on the image type
  precacheImage(new AssetImage('...'), context);
  super.initState();
 }

It gives error. So I removed it.

Comment: error? what error?

Comment: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MediaQuery) or inheritFromElement() was called before
 _TemplatesState.initState() completed.
When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent
widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor
or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
 Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods.

Comment: https://alex.domenici.net/archive/preload-images-in-a-stateful-widget-on-flutter

Comment: Implemented using the above link. But it's still lagging for some second. The image is around 100-200kb. Do you thing this is due to the large image size?

Comment: tried to use a `FutureBuilder` with the `Future` returned by `precacheImage()` function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193078/discussion-between-jazzbpn-and-pskink).

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 11):

Instead of calling `precacheImage()` inside `initState()`, you should do it like this:

```dart
Image myImage;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  myImage= Image.asset(path);
}
  
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  precacheImage(myImage.image, context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to solve the preloading issue. However you could use a `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` for your Stateful Widget's state class (the one containing your grid objects. You will have to make your BodyWidget a `StatefulWidget`) so that you only load each image once and not re-render when the widget goes out of visibility.

```
class _WidgetState extends State<Widget> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Widget>{
….
….
@override
@mustCallSuper
Widget build(BuildContext context)….
….
….
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}'
```

Hope that helps!